# Distribution of infinity-norm over the unit sphere

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I need to compute probabilities of the form
$P( \Vert X \Vert_\infty < r ),$
where $X$ is a random variable of dimension $n$, drawn with a uniform distribution on the unit sphere $\mathcal{S}_{n-1}$. Clearly, the distribution of $Z = \Vert X \Vert_\infty$ is supported by the interval $[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},1]$.

Any hint to get a simple formula (ideally a closed-form expression or a one-dimensional integral) will be greatly appreciated !

**Note:**
Using the fact that $X \sim \frac{Y}{\Vert Y\Vert_2}$ for $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, at first I thought I could first compute the probabilities
$P_i:=P( |X_i| < r \Vert X \Vert_2)$, which can be expressed as a quantile of the F-distribution, but then I realized that those events **are not independent**, so 
$P( \Vert X \Vert_\infty < r ) \neq \prod_{i=1}^n P_i$.

Comment: If $r>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ we have $$P(\|X\|_\infty>r)=nP(X_1>r)=n\int_r^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}^{n-2}C(n)dt.$$
For $r<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ one could use inclusion-exclusion principle to compute probabilities. However I doubt there exist a closed form solution.

Comment: Thanks ! This a a nice trick for the case $r>\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ indeed. What is the function $C(n)$ in the integral ?

Comment: $C(n)$ is the measure of the $n-2$-dimensionale unit sphere.

Comment: @user35593 More precisely, twice your number, no? Because one also has to count $P(X_1<-r)$

Comment: @user35593 In fact, for the 1-sphere one must obtain $\frac4\pi\arccos(r)$ and I cannot obtain this from your formula?

Comment: @guigux: We could get rid of the constant $C(n)$ by division: $P(X_1>r)=\frac{ \int_r^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}^{n-2}dt}{\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}^{n-2}dt}$ and by substituting $t=cos(x)$ we get $P(X_1>r)=\frac{\int_0^{arccos(r)} sin^{n-1}(x)dx }{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} sin^{n-1}(x)dx}$

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: I obtain $\frac{2}{\pi}arccos(r)$ for $n=1$. In your case for $r=0$ we would have probability $>1$.

Comment: @user35593 We probably have shifts of each others' $n$ by one or something? $||X||_\infty=r$ is a square of side $2r$ centered at the origin, right? Thus for $r\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt2}$ probability is $1$, for $r\geqslant1$ it is zero, and for $\frac1{\sqrt2}\leqslant r\leqslant1$ it is the sum of lengths of eight arcs of the unit circle, each with angle $\arccos(r)$, divided by length of the unit circle $2\pi$, no?

Comment: And with your $\frac2\pi\arccos(r)$, for $r=\frac1{\sqrt2}$ one would obtain probability $\frac12$ while it should be $1$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I agree now with $4/arccos(r)$ for the probablity that $\|X\|_{\infty}<r$. I computed $P(X_1>r)$, i.e. the probability that the modulus of the first component is larger than $r$. To get the probability that modulus of the first or second component is larger than $r$ we can just multiply by two because for $r>1/\sqrt{2}$ not both moduli of the components can be simultaneously larger than $r$.

Answer (score -2):

There is a trick to reduce these kinds of questions to questions about independent normals, as in [my ancient preprint.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305252) For large $n,$ concentration of measure will presumably give you easy estimates.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use your result, because the function $\mathbf{1}_{\{\Vert x \Vert_\infty < r\}} (x)$ is not homogeneous of degree $d$ for any $d$ ?

Answer (score -3):

**Edit**: As I write at the end. This is wrong for low dims, but approximately correct for more than a few hundreds, when I guess the coordinates become less dependent.

You can start by uniformly selecting points on the (n − 1)-sphere and then ask what is the infinity norm of such points.

Given a vector $Z$ with $n$ coordinates taken i.i.d. from the normal distribution $Z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. The CDF of the absolute maximum of those is given by considering the CDF of $n$ points drawn from the half normal distribution  $F_{||Z||_{\infty}}(x)={\operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{ x }{\sqrt 2} \right) }^{n}$. Now we need to normalize the points, so they'll be on the unit sphere. Given that the positive squared root of the sum of squared normal variables has a Chi distribution with $n$ degress of freedom, $||Z||_2\sim \chi_n$, we have:

$$P(||X||_{\infty} < r\;|\;||X||_2=1) = \\P(||Z||_{\infty}/||Z||_2 < r) = $$ [wrong transition! (Though it still works in high-dims)]
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} P(||Z||_{\infty}/ ||Z||_2 < r\; |\; ||Z||_2 = x)  f_{\chi_n}(x)\;dx = \\ 
\\\int_{0}^{\infty} F_{||Z||_{\infty}}(x \cdot r) f_{\chi_n}(x)\;dx = \\\int_{0}^{\infty} {\operatorname{erf}\left( \frac{ x \cdot r}{\sqrt 2} \right) }^{n}  \cdot \dfrac{x^{n-1}e^{-x^2/2}}{2^{n/2-1}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}\; dx$$

**Update**

Alternatively, *I'm not entirely sure we can do this*, but I think we can just consider the expected scale of $r$, instead of calculating it as above. It is the mean of $\chi_n$, so the above should be the same as:

$$
F_{||Z||_{\infty}}(\mu(\chi_n) \cdot r)
$$

**Update2**

These formulations seem to be correct for large enough $n$, but not in general:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It cannot be true for all values of $r$ because the last integral is certainly analytic when $r>0$, while the answer definitely isn't.

Comment: The integral is defined over the normalization factor to get to the n-sphere so it is fine.

Comment: Added a simplifying update above. No need to calculate the integral directly. I think.

Comment: *The integral is defined over the normalization factor to get to the n-sphere so it is fine* I don't understand the meaning of this phrase. Neither do I understand how it becomes constant $1$ for large $r$ (I mean the integral with $erf$, of course)

Comment: I'm not sure which part becomes 1? The entire formula? In any case, the integral is the law of total probability over the scale that transforms it into the sphere. $F_{||Z||_\infty}$ is defined over the Normal vector not the n-1-sphere,

Comment: Yes, the entire formula: the last one in the chain. If $r\ge 1$, the whole sphere is there, so the output should be $1$ regardless of $r$.

Comment: It is possible to run simulations to verify this. I'm not even sure what the value is, but the logic overall seems OK. Are you sure it less than 1 for $r \ge 1$?

Comment: Please be aware that every edit of a question or of one of its answers bumps the thread to the front page.
This has happened for this thread already more than 20 times, and this is a nuisance
for other users. Please refrain from unnecessary edits to your posts. -- Usually, the vast majority of
minor edits can be avoided by writing and proofreading a question or an answer (or any update to such)
carefully before posting it.

Comment: Please be aware that there is https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ where you can inquire into your alert notifications issues and preferences.

Comment: Why is normalization of an i.i.d. vector of standard normals uniformly distributed on the unit sphere?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Marsaglia (1972),
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Uniformly_at_random_on_the_(n_%E2%88%92_1)-sphere

Comment: Responding to @StefanKohl's advice with "go and set your alert notifications issues and preferences differently" seems to be missing the point of the modeator's comment.

Comment: @YemonChoi . I understood the comment and found it to be extremely rude. Instead of asking users to change their writing and editing capabilities (just be better at noticing their small typos etc.,), which is quite arrogant IMHO, a more community-inclusive approach would be to inquire with stack overflow meta team on how to throttle notifications on small edits.